# This is a simple login page and somewhere code is not working in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my php code for a login form. Please help i check my code 4-5 time but did not reach out the problem here. The problem is that my if block is executed successfully but else part is not working. I don't what is happening here. Please tell me why my code is not executed properly.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="_SELF">
        <table>
        <tr><td>User<input type="text" name="fuser"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password<input type="password" name="fpassword"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a href="#">Lost Password</a>&nbsp;<a href="form.php">Create new Account</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="fsubmit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fsubmit']))
{
    $hostname="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $dbpassword="";
    $db="php";

    $user=$_POST['fuser'];
    $password=$_POST['fpassword'];
    
    mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $dbpassword) or die("Server not Found, May be connection lost somewhere.");
    
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Error Established, Database Not Connected.");
    
    $query="select * from register where user='$user' and password='$password'";
    
    $rs=mysql_query($query) or die("Query not Executed, Some Fault.");
    
    while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
        if($user==$r['user'] && $password==$r['password'])
        {
            header("Refresh:3; URL=dashboard.php");
        }
        else
        {
            header("Refresh:1; URL=form.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add your error message.

Comment: how do you expect the if statement to fail? you query returns a result set of `user='$user'` and `password='$password'` and your comparing `$user` and `$password` to the results of your query for your if statement. the only way the if statement can fail is if the query returned nothing

Comment: injection risk.

Comment: when i try to login with non registered user then else part is not working and the page goes blank. why this happening.

Comment: Why do you have to compare the passed-on data with the fetched data of your query? It is too redundant, and that loop will slow the process. All you have to do is to use [`*_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) if there is a match. Also consider using [`_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to sanitize POST data from your form before binding it in your query, or better yet, use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: hey @logan wayne i have tried it with as you suggested that was working fine. but i trying to do with this while loop and resultset. is this a good thinking or not.

Comment: does it work properly when you use a registered user? according to [this](http://nimishprabhu.com/header-php-refresh-redirect-location-url-x-seconds.html) *"If you use an echo statement or display any text before setting headers in a PHP page, the header function won’t work."*

Comment: try `mysqli` instead

Comment: Your `else` statement will not work because when a user enters a credential that doesn't exist in your database, it will not enter the loop, which tends not to read the `if-else` statement.

Comment: 1. Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: please give me code, because i never used prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

- Why do you have to compare the passed-on data with the fetched data of your query? It is too redundant, and that loop will slow the process. All you have to do is to use `*_num_rows` if there is a match.
- Also consider using `_real_escape_string()` to sanitize POST data from your form before binding it in your query, or better yet, use prepared statement.
- Your else statement will not work because when a user enters a credential that does not exist in your database, it will not enter the loop, which tends not to read the if-else statement.

**Sample Code:**

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fuser']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fpassword']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE user = '$user' AND password = '$password'";
$rs = mysql_query($query) or die("Query not Executed, Some Fault.");

if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0){

    echo "<script>alert('You Are Login Successfully.')</script>";
    echo "Please Wait We Moving Now, Don't Press F5 or Refresh Button";
    header("Refresh:3; URL=dashboard.php");

} else {

    echo "<script>alert('Sorry Try Agian or Register First.')</script>";
    echo "Please Wait We Moving Now, Don't Press F5 or Refresh Button";
    header("Refresh:1; URL=form.php");

}
```

---

### Prepared Statement:

**Reminder:** [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) API is deprecated, and recommend that you use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

Establish your connection first using `mysqli_*`:

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then, proceed to your code:

```
$user = $_POST['fuser'];
$password = $_POST['fpassword'];

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM register WHERE user = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

    echo "<script>alert('You Are Login Successfully.')</script>";
    echo "Please Wait We Moving Now, Don't Press F5 or Refresh Button";
    header("Refresh:3; URL=dashboard.php");

} else {

    echo "<script>alert('Sorry Try Agian or Register First.')</script>";
    echo "Please Wait We Moving Now, Don't Press F5 or Refresh Button";
    header("Refresh:1; URL=form.php");

}
$stmt->close();
```

---

### Security:

Consider also encrypting your password when storing it in your database. I suggest you use at least [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: thanks alot @logan wayne